# Why does `git log` only display a single line when run in a GitHub Actions workflow?

Tags: bash, git, github-actions

I'm experiencing some strange behavior in GitHub Actions.
I'm attempting to generate a sort of "changelog" between two releases. For this, I format the output of `git log` to become simply a bullet point list of commit hashes and their respective messages.
I do that with this command:

```bash
git log --pretty=format:"- %s (%H)" ${{ steps.previous-release.outputs.tag_name }}..HEAD
```

`steps.previous-release.outputs.tag_name` is the output of [cardinalby/git-get-release-action@v1](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/git-get-release-action) and works correctly.

To export the changelog into a GitHub step output, I run the following:

```yaml
- id: create-changelog
  run: |
    git fetch --all --tags

    {
      echo 'changelog<<EOF'
      git log --pretty=format:"- %s (%H)" ${{ steps.previous-release.outputs.tag_name }}..HEAD
      echo ""
      echo 'EOF'
    } >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

However, despite there being multiple commits between the two targets (I can confirm this locally), the resulting output only contains a single line.

---

Strangely, the extra `echo ""` is necessary. Otherwise, the step results in an error:

```
Error: Unable to process file command 'output' successfully.
Error: Invalid value. Matching delimiter not found 'EOF'
```

It's as if `git log` consumes the character immediately after its output (newline in the example above)? I'm not sure if that gives any clues as to the original issue.

Comment: tl;dr Do you have `fetch-depth: 0` in your checkout step i.e. `actions/checkout@v4`? Seems related to that due to shallow checkout that it performs with its default `fetch-depth: 1`. Also, you may use its `fetch-tags: true` option instead of doing it yourself. See https://github.com/actions/checkout for more details on this.

Comment: That was all it took. Really annoyed that I didn't realize that earlier. Happy to mark it as the answer if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your checkout step, you must be using the default configuration. By default, [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) performs a shallow clone and fetches only the latest commit i.e. `fetch-depth: 1`.

For any `git` operation that requires the complete history, you need to configure [`fetch-depth`](https://github.com/actions/checkout?tab=readme-ov-file#usage) option i.e. `fetch-depth: 0`. That should fix your issue.

Example:

```yaml
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v4
  with:
    fetch-depth: 0
```